# How to make rigid body move smoothly on uneven platform?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

Right now I'm using Rigidbody2d for the game character along with polygon collider 2D(2d platform game).

I'm beginner hope I'm using correct components.

[image]

And transform to move character from left to right.

```
Character.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

And upward(jump).

```
Character.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

When the game character moves on slopes there's lot of friction and bounciness and rotation and its worse when jumping from slopes.

Comment: The answer below about not wanting to use transform.translate is correct, but I suggest you modify the velocity of the RigidBody instead and pass Vector2.up/Vector2.down times the speed only. The implementation of RigidBody will handle the timestep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to move through `Rigidbody` so that you can achieve natural behavior.

To do so, you can follow the following simple steps and write the following code in the script attached to your character.

```
// Class level variable
Rigidbody2D _rb;

void Start()
{
    // Assigning rigidbody2d component to variable
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    // Setting speed along x-axis
    _rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed,_rb.velocity.y);

    // For now it will jump on strike of space key. Please change it according to your input mehtod
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        Jump();
    }
}

void Jump()
{
    // 300 is the jump force. Do change it accordingly.
    _rb.AddForce(0,300);
}
```

Comment: Should i use AddForce to move rigid body in  x axis too?

Comment: AddForce in Update? Don't even think about it :D

Comment: And if you do AddForce in start then gradually your character will get slow down

Comment: Then what should i use for smooth movement in x axis?

Comment: I wrote `_rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed,_rb.velocity.y);` in update

Comment: Character rotates and moves forward now.But  freezing rotation(Z) makes it unnatural when climbing/descending platform.

Comment: Then you can use AddForce in start

Comment: No didn't work its still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34663/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-user75648).

Answer (score 1):

Dont use transform.Translate. it completely ignores collision. Try using rigidbody instead. It will make the movement smoother too

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: After ataching rigidbody, do: Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.getComponent(Rigidbody2D) and then rb.AddForce()

Comment: AddForce makes the character rotate and move forward.

Comment: rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 1000) also, you may neee to cap the speed using rigidbody.velocity.magnitude. There are plenty of tutorials online incuding the unity docs and the original tutorials, you should really look into that